# SparkListener in Spark on YARN-CLUSTER not works?

Tags: apache-spark, listener, hadoop-yarn

My main purpose is to get the `appId` after submitting the yarn-cluster task through java code, which is convenient for more business operations.

Add the `--conf=spark.extraListeners=Mylistener`

While `SparkListener` does work when I use Spark in standalone mode, it doesn't work when I run Spark on a cluster over Yarn. Is it possible for `SparkListener` to work when running over Yarn? If so, what steps should I do to enable that?

Here is the `Mylistener` class code:

```
public class Mylistener extends SparkListener {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EnvelopeSparkListener.class);
    @Override
    public void onApplicationStart(SparkListenerApplicationStart sparkListenerApplicationStart) {
        Option<String> appId = sparkListenerApplicationStart.appId();
        EnvelopeSubmit.appId = appId.get();
        logger.info("====================start");
    }
    @Override
    public void onBlockManagerAdded(SparkListenerBlockManagerAdded blockManagerAdded) {
       logger.info("=====================add");
    }
}
```

Here is the Main class to submit the application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jarpath = args[0];
    String childArg = args[1];
    System.out.println("jarpath:" + jarpath);
    System.out.println("childArg:" + childArg);
    System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hdfs");
    String[] arg = {"--verbose=true", "--class=com.cloudera.labs.envelope.EnvelopeMain",
            "--master=yarn", "--deploy-mode=cluster","--conf=spark.extraListeners=Mylistener","--conf","spark.eventLog.enabled=true", "--conf","spark.yarn.jars=hdfs://192.168.6.188:8020/user/hdfs/lib/*", jarpath, childArg};
    SparkSubmit.main(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the app id you can simply do this,

```
logger.info(s"Application id: ${sparkSession.sparkContext.applicationId}")
```

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: but it will write into a log file,which we do not know where it is . so I want to save this appid in the memory and other class can get it directly,do you have a good idea?

Comment: yea, in that case just assign a reference to it, `val appID = sparkSession.sparkContext.applicationId` and use `appID` where ever you want

Comment: i had tried it ,i use appId after "SparkSubmit.main(arg)",but appid  was null. In other words,I want to use appid on the client which submits the application via java code. And as we know,the client runs on the local,the application runs on the yarn-cluster,so it is hard to get the appId.

Comment: your questions in comments are not aligning with the info you've provided in the original question. the info in the question mentions your deployment mode is set to cluster mode. this means the driver will be running on one of the cluster nodes, since the spark context is created on the driver, you can access the appId on the driver anywhere. if you want to access it on executors, you will probably have to broadcast it using broadcast variables.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my problem description is not very accurate, I will re-describe it.
The machine I submitted the application is not any one in the cluster. When I call "SparkSubmit.main(arg)" directly with java code, I want to get the appId on the machine where the application is submitted. It is neither  on the driver nor on the executors.In addition to the log method, is there any other way to get appId?